# Regex not working in Code behind for Server side validation

Tags: javascript, regex, server-side

I have a js code for validating a textbox. But the problem is that, the same regex is not working in code behind. See the code:-

HTML for the same:-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" class="txtfld-search" oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Please enter numeric values."
OnServerValidate="Validate_Numeric" ControlToValidate="txtSearch"></asp:CustomValidator>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ctl00_topNavigation_txtSearch').keyup(function () {
        var $th = $(this);
        $th.val($th.val().replace(/[^.%a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g,
        function (str) {
            alert('Special characters not allowed except %');
            return '';
        }));
    });
});
```

I am using like this, but it is not working

```
    protected void Validate_Numeric(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("/[^.%a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g");
    e.IsValid = r.IsMatch(txtSearch.Text);
}
```

I want this  `/[^.%a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g`, same regex to be used in Code-behind. 
Please help.

Comment: do you want to replace any character **except**: '.', '%', 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z', '0' to '9', ' '

Comment: I don't know what's `System.Text` but I doubt it takes a string containing / at both ends. The answer to this question is probably in that `System.Text.RegularExpressions` documentation.

Comment: The answer seems to be here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43122zyz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Braj: I dont want to replace, I want that except '%', it does not allow any special characters to be inserted in the textbox. Note: Also, it should be validated server side.

Comment: What you actually want. Can you post the expected result?

Comment: @dystroy: I didn't got your solution. I just want that it should work in code-behind for server-side validation.

Comment: @Gopichandar: I want the textbox to be get server side validated with the regex. I have already mentioned which characters I want and Which i dont want

Comment: @RahulSutar Just read the documentation with its examples, you'll see how your literal regex must be written.

Comment: @dystroy:Ok fine, will going through it. Thanks

Comment: @Gopichandar: Please add it in the answer, if it works i can mark it as answer also. As, i am unable to view it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure.  May be this will help you. The answer will not fit you exactly.  However, you will get an idea to overcome the issue.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


protected void Validate_Numeric(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    string Pattern = @"[^.%a-zA-Z0-9]";
    e.IsValid = Regex.IsMatch(txtSearch.Text, Pattern);    
}
```

Comment: i am using asp.net. how does it will validate my txtSearch textbox ?

Comment: This is just snippet sample. You can take the idea for your code if it works.  Try it in your console whether you are getting the expected result.

Comment: I tried with other code and it worked, got the logic from your code.